# Is there a balancing issue giving a Wizard a wand capable of casting Illusory Script once per day?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew, wizard, rituals

Wizard expressed a desire for a magical wand that could cast the ritual spell *Illusory Script* without burning a spell slot/ritual slot. I though about giving a wand that can cast the spell once per day. Seems relatively fair for a magical item but not sure if there are any balance implications.

Comment: What do you mean by ritual slot? Do you use some homebrew/houserules introducing such a thing?

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: What do you mean by "balance" regarding to non-combat spells?

Comment: @Someone_Evil I meant more about the Ritual Casting that Wizards could do.

Comment: *"cast the ritual spell Illusory Script without burning a spell slot"* — a Wizard don't need a magic item in order to cast a ritual without burning a spell slot; what exactly does the player want?

Comment: Why did you give it to them in the first place? Normally, this spell commonly used, but do you have a need where it's use and value increases?

Comment: @Someone_Evil AFAIK wands in general do not need material components

Comment: @enkryptor: Correct, spells cast from magic items don't require components unless the item says otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## There is no balance issue

But it is so weak that you shouldn't count it towards the magic items the character has if you have some sort of strict resource system. Illusory script is a first level spell that's also a ritual, so a wizard who knows the spell can already cast it whenever they want to as long as they have a couple of minutes of time and the (not very expensive) spell components. The wand doesn't really grant them anything a first level wizard wouldn't already be able to do, so there *can't* be a balance issue even if you ignore the fact that Illusory Script is already a spell with at best marginal utility.

Comment: That's a good point.  I was going to have it be just a Magical Item but not require attunement, that way it doesn't count against the 3 the Wizard can use.